# GitHub page shows readme file instead of index.html but works only if mentioned full path to html file

Tags: github, github-pages

I am new to this and I would really need some help. I am trying to deploy my GitHub page from my GitHub repository. I have set the gh-pages branch as my default, I put the code in there.

The code is in here: https://github.com/MelisaBogdan/melisabogdan.github.io

I tried to check if the website is visible with this link *https://melisabogdan.github.io* but all I see is the readme file. BUT I can perfectly see it by mentioning the folders *https://melisabogdan.github.io/root/index.html*

I know that many people managed to have their website visible without mentioning the full path ( by simply typing https://melisabogdan.github.io).
Is there anything I can do? I would really appreciate some help I tried what some other people suggested....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a NodeJS based site, there are many things that you need to do. Do the following steps to see your portfolio at https://melisabogdan.github.io/ . Basically you need to setup a GitHub action in your repository which runs the NodeJS code & then puts the static HTML/CSS files in your `gh-pages` branch.

1. Change your default branch to `master` by going to your_repo > settings > Branches (on left tab) > Default branch
2. Create a folder `.github` (include that dot) in the master branch

   - create a folder `workflows` within this folder
   - create a file `deploy.yml` inside `workflows` folder
3. Put the following code in `deploy.yml`

```
name: Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.1
        with:
          persist-credentials: false 

      - name: Install and Build 
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build

      - name: Deploy 
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./dist
```

4. So finally the folder structure should be like:
   `melisabogdan.github.io/.github/workflows/deploy.yml`
5. Now commit these files to GitHub
6. Now if you go to the `actions` tab in your repo, should see an action running. It will take 2-3 mins & then finally, you should be able to see your site at https://melisabogdan.github.io/